# Query to get the list of tables in xml format using Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have one query in **sql-server** which gives me details of database tables in **xml** format.

**Query is**:

```
SELECT table_name,column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns 
FOR XML RAW('Table'), ROOT('NewDataSet'), ELEMENTS
```

I want query which gives me same result like above query but in oracle.I want **xml** as output in oracle because I have to read that xml.

Please reply me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[DBMS_XMLGENT.GETXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013206) converts a query into an XML document:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('
    select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
    from dba_tab_columns
    where owner = user')
from dual;


<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <OWNER>JHELLER</OWNER>
  <TABLE_NAME>A</TABLE_NAME>
  <COLUMN_NAME>B</COLUMN_NAME>
  <DATA_TYPE>VARCHAR2</DATA_TYPE>
  <DATA_LENGTH>100</DATA_LENGTH>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```